# How Gridsome handles External Image Url

Tags: vue.js, markdown, gridsome

Can anybody please explain how does Gridsome handles External Image Url in a Markdown File. Does it downloads the image or Simmply renders an External Image using that URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### g-image - relative images

> Gridsome has a built-in  component that outputs an optimized
>   progressive image. It also resizes and crops in real-time when
>   developing.
>
> **Only local, relative image paths will be compressed by Gridsome.**

Related to md:

> The @gridsome/transformer-remark transformer plugin automatically
>   converts normal Markdown images to g-image compatible markup.

Read more: https://gridsome.org/docs/images/

-VS-

### External URL - no render engine

= External Image using that URL

```
---
title: post-1
---


<h2 class="uk-heading-line"><span>Landing Page</span></h2>

<img src ="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416138645715-930585fe4ce2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" title="turtle">

![Landing Page](https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1416138645715-930585fe4ce2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60)
```